# Remove rows from a datatable without affecting the database

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it possible to remove a row from a datatable (C# / .NET 4.5) without having that affect the database? The catch is that I still need to make other changes to the data that should be saved to the database.

Here's a use case:
My application loads a bunch of data and allows the user to manipulate that data. The user can add rows, delete rows, and edit rows. Through an as-yet-to-be-developed notification scheme, my application learns that a specific row was deleted from the database by another entity. My application needs to remove this row from memory. The user no longer sees it; my application no longer processes it.

As mentioned, the user is manipulating other data and must be able to persist their changes. So I can't just delete the row and never call AcceptChanges(). (Most common solution from Google searches.)

My application will also undoubtedly be applying different filters and views to the data. So I can't just throw a filter to "hide" the row. (Or can I? Multiple filters? How would I manage that?)

I need to remove the row from all internal processing, so I can't just set Visible=false on the GUI. (Another fairly common Google search result.)

If I try to call Delete() on the row and apply that, it will fail because the row doesn't exist in the database any more. That would be acceptable as long as all of the other edits still get applied. But it's critical that the user's other edits get saved.

If I simply refresh the data, all of my user's edits will get discarded. And I worry that the same would happen if I copied the remaining rows into a new datatable. (That's another frequent Google search result.)

Comment: Obligatory caching quote: ["There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

Comment: Looks like you need [SignalR with database dependency](http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/) or a modified version of it

Comment: To be a little more constructive though:  Typically the answer is that you don't really need to support a realtime, two-way cache - so to the extent that you can, turn the updates (in one direction or the other) into operations and then refresh the cache. (e.g. Deleted row -> delete operation sent to the DB -> triggers a refresh.)   Or use some middle tier.  But try not to start out supporting generic, unconstrained updates.

Comment: Your problem is solved by CQRS - command query responsibility segregation. In other words, update each row separately. If you update one, and get return "0" rows updated `[command.ExecuteNonQuery]` - you can delete your row. And I also believe, there is something like `HasError` on the row in `DataTable`. YOu then just delete that row and apply changes. Basically, you looking into concurrency. It is solved by various ways.